# How can I override the menu toggle on AdaptiveTheme?

Tags: blocks, routes, theming

The menu renders:

```
<h2 class="block-title at-menu-toggle-button"><a href="#menu-toggle" class="at-menu-toggle-button-link">Menu</a></h2>
```

which is hidden when in a viewport bigger than tablets. I would like to replace the "Menu" part with a `<span>` element with an icon instead, How can I override this?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough I haven't really seen this issue addressed anywhere else.  I found that the most straightforward solution is to put this in your theme's **template.php** and then style the span tag:

```
function your_theme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['block_html_id'] == "block-system-main-menu") {
   $variables['title'] = "<span id='menu-toggle-button-icon'></span>";
  }
}
```

Cheers